# Mongodb Couldn't connect to local server

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

When I tried to connect to Mongodb locally, following error occurred.

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.4
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-05-07T21:34:02.181+0545 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2018-05-07T21:34:02.181+0545 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

I went through some solution in the internet and some of them told that try to run `mongod` first in one terminal and after that run `mongo` in another terminal. I'm using windows and I did this process in my command prompt.

When I tried to run `mongod` at first then following error is encountered -

```
2018-05-07T08:53:18.307-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=4964 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=DESKTOP-8E9NTFH
2018-05-07T08:53:18.308-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2018-05-07T08:53:18.308-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.4
2018-05-07T08:53:18.308-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: d0181a711f7e7f39e60b5aeb1dc7097bf6ae5856
2018-05-07T08:53:18.308-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2o-fips  27 Mar 2018
2018-05-07T08:53:18.308-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-05-07T08:53:18.308-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-05-07T08:53:18.308-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-05-07T08:53:18.308-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
2018-05-07T08:53:18.309-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-05-07T08:53:18.309-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-05-07T08:53:18.309-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2018-05-07T08:53:18.309-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory C:\data\db\ not found., terminating
2018-05-07T08:53:18.309-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2018-05-07T08:53:18.309-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

I tried to uninstall and reinstall `mongodb` but it get stocked here. Need your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongod does not start because the data path does not exist or is not accessible.

```
exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory C:\data\db\ not found
```

Creating the directory should fix the issue.

Comment: I set the --dbpath as C:\mongodb\data\db at the time of installation.

Comment: @DipeshPaudel You must CREATE the directory and it must be readable and writable by the mongod user.

Comment: Thank you @DanFromGermany now the mongo works fine.
Can you give me an idea how to open mongo directly without opening mongod in another cmd.

Comment: @DipeshPaudel I think under windows you either have to use `cmd` or it would normally run as a service I guess. You can have a look into `Windows Event Log` then to see errors from all applications! (Its somewhere near Administrative Tools / System and Security -> View Events).